# Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, push

I've just installed a fresh ionic 3 project, and when I try to add

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=123456789
```

It gives me this strange error

```
    Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-push:
    cordova (0.0.0 in project, >=6.4.0 required)
Fetching highest version of phonegap-plugin-push that this project supports: 1.8.1 (latest is 1.10.3)
```

Which installs the 1.8.1 version which is obviously an unwanted version.

My cordova version is

```
7.0.0
```

1) Any tips on installing the right version of this plugin?

2) For bonus points: How can I get rid of the strange unmet project requirement?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Adding other plugins work fine. Doing (sudo) npm install -g cordova doesn't change anything, as it obviously is already installed.

Comment: If you want to install specific version of plugin then use the @ or # sign and then give the version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Hiten for pointing me in the right direction.

ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@1.10.3 did the trick (had to install cacoapods tho).